# How do I see contents of filesystem directories in Visual Studio Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, solution-explorer

We have some files (config, static files, that sort of thing) in our codebase that are kept in the same filesystem tree as our codebase, but are not part of projects (ie, not underneath a project's tree).

We're after a way of easily managing these from within the IDE.

I dimly recall there being a Visual Studio addin that lets you do something like right-click "open explorer here" or something like that.  Can't find it, now, and it might not even be for VS 2008.

What are the options, if any?

If only solution-folders could display contents of the filesystem (for example)...  Or perhaps there's a "files" project type...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I personally use the Power Commands add-in, which has this functionality along with others that I find helpful.  You can find more information and download from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands).

Comment: I think that's the addin I was thinking of, I think, but I was hoping it would be able to show me a pane like solution-explorer which was actually showing the filesystem instead.

Comment: You might desire an add-in like Mindscape's Visual Studio File Explorer Add-In, which offers a Windows Explorer style file system view.  You can download it and read more information about it @ http://www.mindscape.co.nz/blog/index.php/2008/08/13/free-visual-studio-file-explorer-add-in/.

Comment: Yes!  You, sir, are the winner - the Mindscape add-in was what I dimly recalled.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Solution Explorer Window has a "Show All Files" button, to the left of refresh.

Comment: But this only affects files within a project-tree; my files are not contained underneath a project.